# ANTLR4 lexer yielding 'chars used multiple times in set' error

Tags: antlr, antlr4, lexer

I'm adding a rule to my ANTLR4 lexer that looks like `[/a-zA-Z0-9_?+-.*\u005B-\u005E\u007B-\u007D]+` and it lexes just fine.  However, when I add `\u002C` to it, regardless of where I add that character, or when I add a literal `,` to it, I get the same error:

```
chars ',' used multiple times in set [/a-zA-Z0-9_?+-.*\u005B-\u005E\u007B-\u007D\u002C]
```

There is only one `,` in the set regardless, so I'm unsure what might be causing the error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `-` in `+-.` sequence is interpreted in the same way as in `A-Z`, i.e. as a meta-character that designates a range, not literally as a dash character. The range between `+` and `.` includes `,`:

```
2B: +
2C: ,
2D: -
2E: .
```

If you would like to interpret the dash literally, include it as the last character, right before the closing square bracket.

Comment: Or escape it: `[/a-zA-Z0-9_?+\-.*\u005B-\u005E\u007B-\u007D]+`